# Exclude Screen from Google Analytics V4 Automatic Screen Measurement

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm making use of Automatic Screen Measurement with GA V4 on Android.

I have one activity that I would like to remove from automatic screen measurement.

How do I exclude just one activity ?